# Cython: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got Python object

Tags: python, cython

I have an `np.ndarray` that looks like this:

```
print(x)
[[1 3 None None None None]
 [0 2 3 4 None None]
 [1 5 4 None None None]
 [1 6 0 4 None None]
 [7 6 5 1 3 2]
 [4 7 2 8 None None]
 [7 4 3 None None None]
 [4 6 8 5 None None]
 [7 5 None None None None]]
```

I am supplying it to a cython function defined as follows:

```
cpdef y(int[:,::1] x):
...
```

This throws up the error: ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'int' but got Python object

This is probably happening because of the presence of `None`s in the array, since modifying them to `0`s removes the error. But the presence of `None` should not be posing a problem, as written here: [Cython Extension Types](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#extension-types-and-none)

So, what is going on? Is there a quick solution to this?

Comment: Numpy array such as `a = np.array([1, None])`, `a.dtype` is `object`, that's the problem, `int[:,::1]` expect an int buffer, but got an object buffer

Comment: That documentation reads as though the entire variable can be `None`, whereas you have an array that is made up of `int` and `non-int`/`None` values, which is not valid.

Comment: So, is there an easy correction for this? Can I typecast the `None`s to be integers? Or do I just have to convert the `None`s to some `int` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtype` of numpy array such as `np.array([1, None])` is `object`. `int[:,::1]` expect a buffer of `int`, but get a buffer of `object`, that's the error says.

How to correct this should depend on the context, specifically, what does `None` mean?

1. You can set the `None`s to 0, then convert the array to `int` array

```
a = np.array([[1, None]])
a[a==None] = 0
a = a.astype(np.int)
f(a) # then deal with 0
```

2. Or you can change the cython function signature to `f(double[:, ::1])`

```
a = np.array([[1, None]])
a = a.astype(np.float)
# a will be np.array([1.0, nan]),
# then deal with nan...
f(a)
```

3. Or you may change the cython function signature to `f(object[:, ::1])` (This may not be your intention)

So, it depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Numpys `ma` module (for Masked Array) does what you want:

```
x = np.ma.array([[1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                 [0, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]],
                dtype=np.int,
                mask=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                      [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]]) # True is "masked out"
```

In Cython you'd split it into the data and the mask

```
def y(x):
   cdef int[:,::1] x_data = x.data
   cdef int8_t[:,::1] x_mask = x.mask.view(dtype=np.int8)
```

I've viewed it as an `int8` since Cython doesn't deal well with `dtype=np.bool`.

---

You could also think about creating your own data structures - for example, it looks like it's always the end of the row that is `None`, so you could create an 2D array of `int`s, and a 1D array row lengths (a 1D array of `int`s). You'd then ignore anything beyond the row length.

---

It's probably worth emphasising why you can't store `None` in an `int` array - in order to get the speed and space efficiencies of using an `int` array then Numpy only allocates the space needed to store the numbers. To store `None` would involve allocating a little bit of extra space for every number to say "actually this one is a different type", and for every operation to have a check before it for "is this number actually a number?". As you can imagine that rapidly becomes inefficient.